# How to use http/2 for ASP.NET Core Web app on win 7?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, windows-7, http2

I am writing an ASP.NET Core MVC web app on my Win 7 laptop. The .NET SDK version is 5.0.17.

And when I use a Google API, I get an error

> HttpRequestException: Requesting HTTP version 2.0 with version policy RequestVersionOrHigher while server offers only version fallback

I have found this https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/http2?view=aspnetcore-5.0
which says Kestrel can only use http/2 on Win 10 or higher.

Please help me, if someone know how to use it on Win 7.

Comment: Hi @Bryant, For your error message, I think you need check [the document](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/http) that google api supported protocols include HTTP/1.0, HTTP/1.1, SPDY/*, HTTP/2, and QUIC.

Comment: @Rena Thanks for your response. The doc says "Some API features may only be supported by newer versions of HTTP protocols", in my case, I guess that it needs http/2.
At the end I upgrade my laptop to Win10 to use http/2.